# NSMutableArray of Strings

Tags: objective-c

New Objective-C programmer here trying to make a mutable array of strings.

```
imageNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"Yellow1.png",@"Yellow2.png",@"Yellow3.png","Yellow4.png","Yellow5.png","Yellow6.png",
        "Yellow7.png","Yellow8.png", nil];

    for (NSString *name in imageNames) {
        NSLog(@"%@", name);
    }
```

After running, I receive `(lldb)` in the output log and a a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN, address = 'xxxxxxx'`

Is the string array set up correctly and what would be causing it not to print out the strings in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your strings aren't prefixed with a "@", such as "Yellow5.png".  You'll need to correct that to get them recognized as objects.

Comment: To clarify - string literals that begin with `@` represent `NSString` objects. String literals without the `@` are considered C-string literals which are not objects.

Comment: Yes you're correct, sorry was answering while cooking dinner. :)